# Responsive sizing of image inside flex div

Tags: html, css

Greeting all:

I am struggling a bit with how to make sure my image resizes properly inside a `flex` div:

```
<div id="header" style="display:flex;width:100%;">
   <div style="height:100%;width:auto;">
      <img src="filename.png" alt="Avatar" style="height:100%;width:auto"></img>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is a header on the page and I want the image to show up within the confines of the header and resize if the browser is resized.

Comment: what have you tried so far? why not using `object-fit` to achieve the wanted outcome? Also, image `<img>` is an empty tag. It has no closing tag.

Comment: I edited the code.  I've tried so many things including the `object-fit` property, but the image always shows as full size and expands the header.

Comment: the height 100% in the wrapping div is the actual issue. If you change it to some more definite like 100vh, then object fit contain will work fine. Height of 100% will sue 100% of the contents height.